# Prove there exist a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that all entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ are $0$ except row $j$ and column $j$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Prove that there exist a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to these bases, all entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ are $0$ except that the entries in row $j$, column $j$, equal 1 for $1 \leq j \leq$ dim range$T$.

My thought:

- I need to find an example of basis of $V$, and basis of $W$ that fulfill the requirements
- Then, if the basis of $V$ is $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, if I choose the "basis" (not a basis actually) of $W$ is $Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_n$, then the matrix is 1 in diagonal line, and zero in others.

But,  $Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_n$ is not (I am not sure) a basis of $W$. How can I move from that?

Is $Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_n$ a basis of $W$?

I found the answer [here](http://linearalgebras.com/3c.html). But I don't understand the extending basis part.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=\dim V$, $m=\dim W$ and $r=\dim\operatorname{range}T$. Then, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\ker T=n-r$. So, pick a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ of $\operatorname{range}T$. For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,r\}$, take $v_k\in V$ such that $T(v_k)=w_k$. Then, since $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ is linearly independent, so is $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$. Now, add to $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ a basis of $\ker T$ (which will have $n-r$ elements) and complete $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ so that you have a basis of $W$. And you're done!

Comment: Thank you. I understand your explanation up to THen, since {w1,…,wr} is linearly independent, so is {v1,…,vr}. 

What is the use of adding a basis of ker T to  {v1,…,vr}. And what does it mean by  complete  {w1,…,wr}

Comment: If we had $\alpha_1v_1+\cdots\alpha_rv_r=0$ in a situation in which no all $\alpha_k$'s are $0$, then we would have $\alpha_1T(v_1)+\cdots\alpha_rT(v_r)=0$, which would mean that $\alpha_1w_1+\cdots\alpha_rw_r=0$. We add a basis of $\ker T$ to $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ so that we have a basis of $V$. And we complete $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ adding to it enough vectors so that we have a basis of $W$.

Comment: Why adding a basis of $Ker T$ to ${v_1,...,v_r}$ is the basis of $V$? Is that because the dimension of ${v_1,...,v_r}$ is $r$ and ker $T$ is n-r, then the sum is $n$ which is the dimension of $V$?

The reason I have this confusion is that, by linear independent list extends to a basis, we need to have a linear independent list in $V$, and a basis in $V$. The vector space is the same. But in this example, Ker T is a subspace of $V$. So, I am wondering, after I extend it, will I only get different basis of Ker T .

Comment: After you extend it, you do *not* get a basis of $\ker T$. What you get is a basis of $V$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The fact that $\{v_{r+1},\dots,v_{n}\}$ is not necessarily a subset of the kernel means that the matrix of the transformation may have non-zero entries to the right of the $r$th column, contrary to the requirements of the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By the way, I'm looking at this due to [this recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3901634/81360)

Comment: @BenGrossmann Why do you say that $\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ is not necessarily a subset of the kernel? I defined it as a *basis* of $\ker T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Somehow I misread your answer earlier... not sure how I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out.