# understanding relation of matrix and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I  was reading Sheldon Axler's book question 3.c.3 which is answered here:
[3.c.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130784/prove-there-exist-a-basis-of-v-and-a-basis-of-w-such-that-all-entries-of-m)
but I can't understand how it works.
can anyone give me explanation and some intuition about relation of them please.
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIOF7.png)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is it exactly is it that you don't understand? At the very least, what is the first line from the answer that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't get it for example why the first element of basis of V which was in null T in matrix is something like    T(v1) = 1*w1+...+0*wr why 1 is multiplied I think it should be 0 either

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you have written is not a line from the answer, and so I have no idea what you're talking about. In any case, I think the answer on that post is incorrect

Comment: I add the proof to my question

Comment: Great, and this proof is similar to what I would have written to answer this question. I assume that you now want an explanation of how this other proof works. As before, it would be helpful if you could go through this proof and point to the first sentence that you don't understand.

Comment: from part with respect to the basis.... .I don't get it why this is wat we wanted

Comment: The entire proof is "the part with respect to the basis", I'll need you to be more specific. Let's try this instead: if you read through the last paragraph, can you understand why (based on the earlier part of the proof) we have $Tv_i = w_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$? Do you understand why we have $Tu_i = 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,m$?

Comment: yes I understood that

Comment: *Now* I understand. You mean that you don't understand the relationship between a transformation and its matrix; I missed that you already said this because you said this in the question's title but not the body of the question. When I get the chance, I'll write an answer accordingly

Comment: yes exactly, I will be really thankful

Comment: Actually the linked proof was ok; I had misread something

Comment: @BenGrossmann oh thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to relate a transformation to its matrix is to note that the $j$th column of a matrix specifies the image of the $j$th basis element of the domain.

In our case, the bases are $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$.

For $1 \leq j \leq n$, the image of the $i$th basis element is given by
$$
T(v_j) = w_j = 0 \cdot w_1 + \cdots + 0 \cdot w_{j-1} + 1 \cdot w_j + 0 \cdot w_{j+1} + \cdots + 0 \cdot w_n.
$$
Correspondingly, the $j$th column of $\mathcal M(T)$ will be $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$. Thus, the $j$th entry of the $j$th column is $1$, and all other entries of the column are $0$. This gives us the expected result for the first $n$ columns.

For $j>n$, we find that the image of the $j$th basis vector is given by
$$
T(u_{j-n}) = 0 = 0 \cdot w_1 + \cdots + 0 \cdot w_p,
$$
which means that the $j$th column will be $(0,\dots,0)$. In other words, all entries outside the first $n$ columns are $0$.

Comment: thank you very much that was really helpful